# Print lines in between two patterns using awk or sed

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to parse through the output from a file by first grep the lines finding two patterns starts with unique string (ie ATOM, !) and then find another patterns (PVAL, PLMS) in this grep lines and print. For example

```
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL01 
 PRNT 16 
 PVAL    7.243  SIGPV    0.038 
 PLMS 1  1  -0.034   PLMS 3  1  -0.050 
 PLMS 3  3  -0.063   PLMS 4  4   0.016
! 
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL02
 NIEG 2
 PVAL    7.242  SIGPV    0.008 
 PLMS 1  1  -0.046   PLMS 3  1  -0.011 
 PLMS 3  3   0.072   PLMS 4  4   0.019 
!
ATOM 9 COMMENT F01
 NEIG 4 
 EXCEPT OH 
 PVAL    7.185   SIGPV    0.031
 PLMS 1  1  -0.064   PLMS 2 -2   0.005
 PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 4  2  -0.006
 PLMS 4  4   0.006
!
```

Expected o/p should be

```
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL01 PVAL    7.243  SIGPV    0.038 PLMS 1  1  -0.034   PLMS 3  1  -0.050 PLMS 3  3  -0.063   PLMS 4  4   0.016

ATOM 17 COMMENT CL02  PVAL    7.242  SIGPV    0.008 PLMS 1  1  -0.046   PLMS 3  1  -0.011 PLMS 3  3   0.072   PLMS 4  4   0.019

ATOM 9 COMMENT F01 PVAL    7.185   SIGPV    0.031 PLMS 1  1  -0.064   PLMS 2 -2   0.005 PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 4  2  -0.006 PLMS 4  4   0.006
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '/^ATOM/{ f=1; r=$0 }/^!/{ print r; f=0 }f && ($1~/^(PVAL|PLMS)/){ r=r OFS $0 }' file
```

The output:

```
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL01   PVAL    7.243  SIGPV    0.038   PLMS 1  1  -0.034   PLMS 3  1  -0.050   PLMS 3  3  -0.063   PLMS 4  4   0.016
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL02  PVAL    7.242  SIGPV    0.008   PLMS 1  1  -0.046   PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 3  3   0.072   PLMS 4  4   0.019 
ATOM 9 COMMENT F01  PVAL    7.185   SIGPV    0.031  PLMS 1  1  -0.064   PLMS 2 -2   0.005  PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 4  2  -0.006  PLMS 4  4   0.006
```

Comment: @user31735 Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks, now I did what I supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Even below one can give desired output, if your real input file is same as what you have posted.

```
# either
awk  'f=/ATOM|PVAL|PLMS|!/{ORS=/^!/?RS:OFS; if(/^!/)$1=""}f' infile

# or
awk  'f=/ATOM|PVAL|PLMS/{ORS=OFS}!f && f=/!/{ORS=RS; $1=""}f' infile
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL01 
 PRNT 16 
 PVAL    7.243  SIGPV    0.038 
 PLMS 1  1  -0.034   PLMS 3  1  -0.050 
 PLMS 3  3  -0.063   PLMS 4  4   0.016
! 
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL02
 NIEG 2
 PVAL    7.242  SIGPV    0.008 
 PLMS 1  1  -0.046   PLMS 3  1  -0.011 
 PLMS 3  3   0.072   PLMS 4  4   0.019 
!
ATOM 9 COMMENT F01
 NEIG 4 
 EXCEPT OH 
 PVAL    7.185   SIGPV    0.031
 PLMS 1  1  -0.064   PLMS 2 -2   0.005
 PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 4  2  -0.006
 PLMS 4  4   0.006
!
```

Output-1:

```
$ awk  'f=/ATOM|PVAL|PLMS|!/{ORS=/^!/?RS:OFS; if(/^!/)$1=""}f' infile
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL01   PVAL    7.243  SIGPV    0.038   PLMS 1  1  -0.034   PLMS 3  1  -0.050   PLMS 3  3  -0.063   PLMS 4  4   0.016 
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL02  PVAL    7.242  SIGPV    0.008   PLMS 1  1  -0.046   PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 3  3   0.072   PLMS 4  4   0.019  
ATOM 9 COMMENT F01  PVAL    7.185   SIGPV    0.031  PLMS 1  1  -0.064   PLMS 2 -2   0.005  PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 4  2  -0.006  PLMS 4  4   0.006
```

Output-2:

```
$ awk  'f=/ATOM|PVAL|PLMS/{ORS=OFS}!f && f=/!/{ORS=RS; $1=""}f' infile
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL01   PVAL    7.243  SIGPV    0.038   PLMS 1  1  -0.034   PLMS 3  1  -0.050   PLMS 3  3  -0.063   PLMS 4  4   0.016  
ATOM 17 COMMENT CL02  PVAL    7.242  SIGPV    0.008   PLMS 1  1  -0.046   PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 3  3   0.072   PLMS 4  4   0.019  
ATOM 9 COMMENT F01  PVAL    7.185   SIGPV    0.031  PLMS 1  1  -0.064   PLMS 2 -2   0.005  PLMS 3  1  -0.011   PLMS 4  2  -0.006  PLMS 4  4   0.006
```